# Chrome Extension Code: LOL Link Sharer

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome

I made a hacky version of a chrome extension to compliment a weekly literary/arts publication. The extension helps me curate links from my publication's readers since there's only so much I can curate and read/watch.

Users sign in through google and can share the link of the opened tab to me.

I'm new to programming. Any kind of code review / suggestion would be highly appreciated. I've opened three issues that I see I need to correct on github repo already, please feel free to highlight and open more.

I'm using firebase auth and database for persistent storage.

[LOL Chrome Extension Github Repo](https://github.com/gdad-s-river/LOL-Chrome-Extension)

Main code of the repo, in which I'd need review is as follows

```
// LOL-Chrome-Extension/src/js/credentials.js

  let signInBtn = document.querySelector("#sign-in"),
  signOutBtn = document.querySelector("#sign-out"),
  clickBait = document.getElementById('google-sign-in-btn'),
  loader = document.querySelector(".loader"),
  linkShareBtn = document.querySelector(".send-link-btn")

// Wrapper Functions
function crGetSignInStatus(key, cb) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(key, (status) => {
    cb(status[key])
  })
}

function crStoreSignInStatus(val, cb) {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    "signInStatus": val
  }, () => {
    console.log("Signed In? ", val)
  })
}

function toggleBtns(signInStatusVal) {
  if(signInStatusVal) {
    signInBtn.style.display = "none"
    signOutBtn.style.display = "block"

    linkShareBtn.classList.remove("hide");
    linkShareBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

      // Ripple effect

      let scali = document.querySelector(".scali")
      scali.classList.remove("animate");

      let computedStylesScali  = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".scali"))

      if( !computedStylesScali.width && !computedStylesScali.height  ) {
        let d = Math.max(linkShareBtn.offsetWidth, linkShareBtn.offsetHeight)
        scali.style.height = d
        scali.style.width = d
      }

      let offsetObj = linkShareBtn.getBoundingClientRect(),
       offsetTop = offsetObj.top + document.body.scrollTop,
       offsetLeft = offsetObj.left + document.body.scrollLeft

      let x = e.pageX - offsetLeft - computedStylesScali.width / 2

      let y = e.pageY - offsetTop - computedStylesScali.height / 2

      scali.style.top = y + "px"
      scali.style.left = x + "px"

      scali.classList.add("animate");

      // ripple effect end

      loader.classList.remove("hide");
      console.log(e.target, " was clicked")

      let currentUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].uid

      chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){

       let newLinkRef = firebase.database().ref().child("links").push()
       let newLinkKey = newLinkRef.key

       async function writeLinks() {
         try {
          await Promise.all([
            firebase.database()
              .ref("users/" + currentUserId)
              .child("links")
              .child(newLinkKey).set({
                url: tabs[0].url
              }),

            newLinkRef.set({
              uid: currentUserId,
              url: tabs[0].url
            })
          ])

          loader.classList.add("hide")
         } catch ( error ) {
           console.log(error);
         }
       }

       writeLinks();

      });
    })

  } else {
      signInBtn.style.display = "block"
      signOutBtn.style.display = "none"

      linkShareBtn.classList.add("hide");
      linkShareBtn.removeEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("click event on share button is removed")
      })
  }
}

class LOL {
  constructor(...args) {
    this.init.bind(this);
  }

  initFirebase() {
    const config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCLh6M0BKhcihuFWioSVn30z1euZsEF79A",
      databaseURL: "https://lol-chrome-extension.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "lol-chrome-extension.appspot.com"
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

  firebaseAuthStateObserver() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( (user) => {
      if(user) {
        let {
          displayName,
          email,
          photoURL,
          uid
        } = user.providerData[0]

      } else {
        // share button disabled
      }
    })
  }

  attachSignInClickEvent() {
    clickBait.addEventListener("click", this.handleSignInOut.bind(this), false)
  }

  startSignIn(interactive) {
    loader.classList.remove("hide")

    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: !!interactive}, (token) => {
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError && !interactive) {
        console.error("It wasn't possible to get a token programmatically")
      } else if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      } else if (token) {
        let credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token)
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
          .then( (...args) => {

            crStoreSignInStatus(true, () => {})

            // abstract it
            loader.classList.add("hide");

            crGetSignInStatus("signInStatus", toggleBtns)

            const userInfo = args[0];
            const { uid, displayName, email, photoURL } = userInfo.providerData[0];

            console.log("signin userinfo", userInfo)
            this.firebasePostUser({ uid, displayName, email, photoURL })


            // write end
          })
          .catch( (error) => {
            if(error.code === "auth/invalid-credential") {
              chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({ token: token}, () => {
                this.handleSignInOut(interactive)
              })
            }
          })
      }
    })
  }

  handleSignInOut() {
    if(firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      firebase.auth().signOut();
      crStoreSignInStatus(false, () => {})
      crGetSignInStatus("signInStatus", toggleBtns)
    } else {
      this.startSignIn(true);
    }
  }

  firebasePostUser(userInfoObj) {
    const { displayName, email, photoURL, uid } = userInfoObj;

    let userRef = firebase.database().ref("users/" + uid);

    userRef.once('value', (snap) => {
      let exists = (snap.val() !=null );
      console.log(exists);

      if(!exists) {
        userRef.set({
          name: displayName,
          email,
          photoURL,
          createdAt: new Date().getTime()
        })
      }
    })

  }
  init() {
    this.initFirebase()
    this.firebaseAuthStateObserver()
    this.attachSignInClickEvent()
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  crGetSignInStatus("signInStatus", toggleBtns)
  let lol = new LOL();
  lol.init();
}
```